# Not all attributes are populated from Backbone model, to Rails backend when doing save

Tags: backbone.js, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to implement simple demo, based on backbone.js and rails4. For this purpose I've created simple model:

```
app.LocationModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    name : "Test name",
    description : "Test description",
  },
});
```

Later somewhere in the code, I put to the model latitude and longitude taken from Google marker object. Then I call save on the model. In Chrome dev tools I see that Request Payload in POST request contains following information:

```
{"pos":{"latitude":52.30511992110524,"longitude":16.2103271484375},"name":"Test name","description":"Test description"}
```

That is correct. On the Rails side I'm trying to receive these JSON object and persist in database in a way:

```
def create
  @location = Location.new(location_params)
  if @location.save
    render json: @location
  end
end
```

...
where:

```
def location_params
  puts "test #{params.permit(:name, :description, :pos)}"
  params.permit(:name, :description, :pos)
end
```

Test put shows: `test {"name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description"}`

Location db table looks like that:

```
create_table :locations do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :description
  t.float :latitude
  t.float :longitude
  t.timestamps
end
```

Unfortunately, from unknown for me reason, this "pos" information (latitude & longitude) are not persisted (are nulls). The strange thing happens in server logs, when there are displayed information about parameters taken from request:

```
Processing by LocationsController#create as JSON   Parameters: {"pos"=>{"latitude"=>52.562995039558004, "longitude"=>16.38336181640625}, "name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description", "location"=>{"name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description"}} Geokit is using the domain: localhost Unpermitted parameters: pos, location test {"name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description"} Unpermitted parameters: pos, location    (0.2ms)  begin transaction   SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "locations" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-13 09:28:59.092248"], ["description", "Test description"], ["name", "Test name"], ["updated_at", "2014-08-13 09:28:59.092248"]]    (162.1ms)  commit transaction Completed 200 OK in 169ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord:
163.8ms)
```

Why when there are displayed parameters there is an location object => but without "pos" information ? I guess this is also a root cause why there is displayed message about unpermitted "pos" and finally these long & lat are not passed to insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Location` model has separate `latitude` and `longitude` attributes:

```
create_table :locations do |t|
  #...
  t.float :latitude
  t.float :longitude
  #...
end
```

rather than a single `pos` attribute. If you say:

```
Location.new(:name => '...', :description => '...', :pos => { ... })
```

then you'll get a `Location` with only `name` and `description` attributes since `Location` doesn't know anything about `pos`.

You'll have a better time if everything matches your model all the way down. Your Backbone model should be sending in:

```
{
  "latitude": 52.30511992110524,
  "longitude": 16.2103271484375,
  "name": "Test name",
  "description":"Test description"
}
```

and your controller's parameter checking should look like:

```
def location_params
  params.permit(:name, :description, :latitude, :longitude)
end
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought and finally I've implemented like that... Also my understanding why "pos" is not a part of Location displayed based on received by controller parameters (only name and description):

Processing by LocationsController#create as JSON   Parameters: {"pos"=>{"latitude"=>52.562995039558004, "longitude"=>16.38336181640625}, "name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description", "location"=>{"name"=>"Test name", "description"=>"Test description"}}

Is because Rails model doesn't know anything about "pos" or ?

Comment: Like I said, "`Location` doesn't know anything about `pos`" so the `Location` model will ignore any `pos` that you give it.